# How can i inject url into razor url in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What im trying to do here is getting a json url from string argument.
My View
my view name is Admin/Index

```
function blablasub(){

    submitter("ParentList", "ChildListTextArea", "~/Admin/DesignSubmit/", "ides", "productid");
}
```

and wanna try using these in the function below.

```
function submitter(chosenListBox, chosenTextBox, jsonurl, textparameter, listparameter) {
    var ListBox = $("select#" + chosenListBox);
    var ListBoxVal = $("select#" + chosenListBox + " option:selected").val();
    if (ListBoxVal == "" || ListBoxVal == 0) {
        ListBox.css('background-color', '#FFBBBB');
    } else {
        ListBox.css('background-color', 'white');

        var TextBox = $("#" + chosenTextBox);
        var TextBoxVal = $("#" + chosenTextBox).val();
        if (TextBoxVal == "" || TextBoxVal == 0) {
            $("#" + chosenTextBox).css('background-color', '#FFBBBB');
        } else {
            TextBox.css('background-color', 'white');
            alert(ListBox.toString() + " - " + TextBox.toString() + " - " + '@Url.Content(" + jsonurl.toString() + ")' + " - " + textparameter.toString() + " - " + listparameter.toString() + " - Finito Baby");
            $.getJSON('@Url.Content(" + jsonurl.toString() + ")', { textparameter: TextBoxVal, listparameter: ListBoxVal }, function (data) {
                clearitem("#" + chosenListBox);
                $("#" + chosenListBox).removeAttr('disabled');
                $.each(data, function (i, c) {
                    $("#" + chosenListBox).append('<option value="' + c.Value + '">' + c.Text + '</option>');
                })
                $("#" + chosenListBox + " option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
                $("#" + chosenListBox).change("#" + chosenListBox + "list");
            })
        }
    }
}
```

so how can i inject the url as string into razor `@Url.Content()` ?

Edit:
My Controller

my controllers name is AdminController

```
    public JsonResult ProductSubmit(string ipro, Product prod)
    {
        prod.name = ipro;
        db.Products.InsertOnSubmit(prod);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        int pro = Convert.ToInt32(db.Products.Where(x => x.name == ipro).Select(x => x.id).Single());
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items = db.Products.Where(d => d.id == pro).AsEnumerable().Select(c => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = c.name,
            Value = c.id.ToString()
        });
        SelectList data = new SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text");
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult DesignSubmit(string ides, Design des, int productId)
    {
        des.name = ides;
        des.master_id = productId;
        db.Designs.InsertOnSubmit(des);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items = db.Designs.Where(x => x.master_id == productId).AsEnumerable().Select(c => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = c.name,
            Value = c.id.ToString()
        });
        SelectList data = new SelectList(Items, "Value", "Text");
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: where is `blablasub` defined?

Comment: i know i overcomplicated things up there but its how i like it to do.
i just wanna learn posible ways to get the url from some other function as string and inject into razor url.

Comment: blablasub defined as another function which gets triggered by a button. its not in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: i tried it works till url part thats why i use alert there..

Comment: blabla sub is being used in a view named as index of admin controller
i ve no problem with firing functions the problem stands with url part 
'@Url.Content("my url will be here as a string argument")' so all these codes that i showed in the same view index, there is no file that is being changed or fired across.
to be more specific ill edit and put an example of my controller.

Comment: i know its used as :
'@Url.Content("~/Admin/ProductSubmit/")'

but its not my problem my problem putting it with an argument like this 
string argJsonUrl = "~/Admin/ProductSubmit/";
'@Url.Content(argJsonUrl)'

can i put url like this is there a way to inject code like this into razor i wanna learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Url.Content` method is executed and output server-side. As such the javascript value for the url, which is client side, is not present when the razor file is parsed. So what we need to do is make sure the `Url.Content` is executed before the javascript is called like so:

Assuming your `blahblah` function is within your view. (based on your comment above)

```
function blablasub(){                                   /*works this way..*/
    submitter("ParentList", "ChildListTextArea", '@Url.Content("~/Admin/DesignSubmit/")', "ides", "productid");
}


$.getJSON(jsonurl, { textparameter: TextBoxVal, listparameter: ListBoxVal }, function (data) {
...
});
```